# Validation error: Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'

Tags: swagger

I'm getting the error `Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'` with the following spec:

```
{
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "REST API"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/doit": {
      "post": {
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response"
          }
        },
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ResponseDefinition"
            },
            "required": "true",
            "name": "docs",
            "in": "body"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "definitions": {
    "ResponseDefinition": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This full errorfrom the swagger-tools validator:

```
#/paths/~1doit/post/parameters/0: Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'
#/paths/~1doit/post/parameters/0: Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'
  #/required: Expected type boolean but found type string
  #/: Missing required property: type
#/paths/~1doit/post/parameters/0: Additional properties not allowed: in,name,required,schema
```

I don't understand the error or how to resolve.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't include `type` in a `body` parameter. That's why there's the `schema`. Try this:

```
{
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "REST API"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/doit": {
      "post": {
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response"
          }
        },
        "parameters": [
          {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ResponseDefinition"
            },
            "required": "true",
            "name": "docs",
            "in": "body"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "definitions": {
    "ResponseDefinition": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind citing where you got this factoid from ?

Comment: What factoid are you referring to?

Comment: The first line of your response.

Comment: Check the fields table under https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterObject.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was incorrect apidoc that led to the error. This doc produced the error:

```
/**
 * @openapi
 * /init:
 *   get:
 *     description: Tells the app an environment it should use
 *     parameters:
 *       - name: version
 *         in: query
 *         description: app version, for example "4.0.0"
 *         required: true
 *         type: string
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Description
 */
```

Please note there is a `type` right under `parameters`

When I put `type` under `parameters` -> `schema` it started to be valid:

```
/**
 * @openapi
 * /init:
 *   get:
 *     description: Tells the app an environment it should use
 *     parameters:
 *       - name: version
 *         in: query
 *         description: app version, for example "4.0.0"
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: string
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Description
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I put wrong Model Bindings for my API. 
I put **FromQuery** instead of **FromBody**